# remote debug success with ccs5 and CodeSourery, but fail with eclipse, why?

Tags: gdb, eclipse-cdt, cdi

I use gdb and gdbserver on target, remote debug success in shell, ti's ccs5 and codesourery,but when i try the eclipse to do the ssme thing, it fail.

```
"Failed to execute MI command"

"help maintenance set"

(gdb) help maintenance set
```

Set GDB internal variables used by the GDB maintainer.
Configure variables internal to GDB that aid in GDB's maintenance

List of maintenance set subcommands:

```
maintenance set dwarf2 -- Set DWARF 2 specific variables
maintenance set internal-error -- Configure what GDB does when internal-error is detected
maintenance set internal-warning -- Configure what GDB does when internal-warning is detected
maintenance set profile -- Set internal profiling
```

Log:

```
Error in final launch sequence
Failed to execute MI command:
maintenance set python print-stack off
Error message from debugger back end:
Undefined maintenance set command: "python print-stack off".  Try "help maintenance set".
```

Comment: It looks like your gdb is not entirely supported by CDT (it asks for the version and then configures itself based on gdb version). Can you provide what your GDB prints for a version so I compare it against CDT sources? Have you tried disabling pretty-printing on C/C++->Debug->GDB preference page?

Comment: Argh, I guess disabling pretty-print will not work (from looking at sources). You need to somehow make CDT recognize it as pre-7.0 GDB...